# Why 'input' event has `Event` type of event instead of `InputEvent`

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom, types, inputevent

Hi I am wondering why type of **`'input'`** event type is a `Event` type (I thought it should be `InputEvent`)?

I came across on this problem doing this:

```js
interface OnInputTextFieldListenerProps extends BaseTextFieldListenerProps {
    eventName: Extract<keyof GlobalEventHandlersEventMap, 'input'>;
    callback(e?: InputEvent): void;
}

if (isOnInputTextFieldProps(listenerProps)) {
    this.input.addEventListener<'input'>(listenerProps.eventName, listenerProps.callback.bind(this));
}
```

And now i am getting this error:

> TS2345: Argument of type '(e?: InputEvent | undefined) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: HTMLInputElement, ev: Event) => any'.

Which is fully correct. But why `GlobalEventHandlersEventMap` **`'input'`** is typed as `Event` instead of `InputEvent`.

You can find this `GlobalEventHandlersEventMap` interface here **[lib.dom.d.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/da5ff57608dd73247b898812c9fccca285969ab3/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L5715)** at line **`5715`**.

#### Note

[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) says that `GlobalEventHandlers.oninput` interface is `InputEvent`. `oninput` is probalby equivalent of typescript `input`. I think like that because in MDN docs every key of `GlobalEventHandlers` interface starts with `on`.

> I also decided to open an issue in Typescript repo which you can find here: [Issue - 39925](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39925)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the main reason of why this `'input'` event is type of `Event` instead of `InputEvent` is that `InputEvent` is a part of [draft specification](https://w3c.github.io/input-events/#interface-InputEvent) **NOT** [official HTML living standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#event-input).

If you want to learn more you can read **[the whole answer](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39925#issuecomment-669550088)** provided by *Andrew Branch*